# How to change the drag and drop cursor when mouseover a drop target

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drag-and-drop

I have an app that incorporates a drop target to unarchive (file attribute) files.  I would like to change the mouse cursor in the DragEnter event of the form to a custom cursor (.cur) that I have as an embedded resource.

The drop target is a transparent form with an image of a target.  (The entire form is the drop target)

I know I can use the GiveFeedBack event when I have control of the drag source.  However this is not the case as the source is Windows explorer.  (and maybe I'm wrong and I can still use GiveFeedBack in this scenario, but I could not figure out how to trigger the event.)

To eliminate the possibility that my custom cursor was not valid or corrupt, I successfully set the custom cursor in the MouseOver event of the drop target form.

Functionally everything is working, I am now just wanting to "pretty things up" a little bit.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to know already that custom cursors are set in GiveFeedBack and how to do that. The problem then is that you are not getting any GiveFeedBack events. I don't know on what control you have a drop spot, but try attaching a listener to the underlying Form's GiveFeedBack event, and see if you get any feedback there.

You can also try subclassing the control you are using (Panel, PictureBox or whatever) and listening to its GiveFeedBack event.

Comment: My drop target is an entire form.  Essentially I have a small transparent form that has a picture of a target on it. I have tried adding a listener and the GiveFeedBack event is never triggered.