# How can the drop target override the cursor shape in a drag and drop originating from the outside?

Tags: mfc, drag-and-drop, cursor

I have an MFC window which acts as a drop target. Depending on where the user drops certain types of data, I'd like to change the cursor shape to indicate what action will occur, only the actions are not move/copy/link, but more complex actions for which I have custom cursors.

Here's an example, if it helps. Imagine I have a window with 2 squares where the user can drop a file: in the first square, the file is e-mailed, in the second, the file is stored on Dropbox. I have one e-mail cursor and one dropbox cursor, and I'd like the cursor to change accordingly when the user hovers over the squares.

In MFC, you can create a *COleDropSource* object and override its *GiveFeedback()* method to do exactly this. However, this only works if you can pass that object to *COleDataSource::DoDragDrop()*, ie if you start the drag operation yourself. If the drag originates inside my application, this method works and I can get the desired cursor type. If the drag originates from Windows Explorer, I don't have a chance of providing my own *COleDropSource* object, and so I can't override the cursor shape.

Setting the cursor directly in OnDragOver() does not work, since Windows uses the result value of that method to change the cursor, so I only see the desired cursor for a fraction of a second before Windows changes it back to one of the standard shapes.

Is there any other way of solving this?

(This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234150/how-to-change-the-drag-and-drop-cursor-when-mouseover-a-drop-target), only I'm using MFC so the proposed solution there does not work.)

Comment: Not possible, the drop source is in control.  You can alter the target appearance any way you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid the source application is reponsible for the user feedback. You can provide hints to the source application via IDropTarget but it's the sources reponsiblity for using that feedback.

It makes sense really, the source application is the one that really knows what the data is and what can be done with it (think dragging a file from a zip file etc.).